# Jquery not acting as expected

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have options for users to choose. These options when clicked cause more options to appear and text box's as well.

I am having an issue with one part that I thought I had mastered. The code is a copy paste of all the other options but this specific one just does not work. The other ones work just fine.

This is a snippet of the code :

```
if ($("#onlyother").is(":checked")) {
    $("#counselorcomments").show("fast");
} else {
    $("#counselorcomments").css("display", "none");
}
```

That part above is the snippet of code that is supposed to check on page load if the option (#onlyother) is checked.

I have implemented this sort of functionality to all my options and all work fine except for this one.

```
$(".action").click(function() {
    if ($("#add").is(":checked")) {
        $(".forms").show("fast");
    } else {
        $(".forms").hide("fast");
    }
    if ($("#onlyother").is(":checked")) {
        $("#counselorcomments").show("fast");
    } else {
        $("#counselorcomments").hide("fast");
    }
});
```

This snippet of code is what I use to actually choose between the options. (This work as expected.

```
<label class ="action"><input type="radio" name="action" value="Other" id="onlyother" <?php echo set_radio('action', 'Other'); ?>/><font color="#ff0000" size="2"><strong>Other</strong></font></label>
```

This is the radio button that is causing issues.

And this is the box that has to appear / disappear

```
<textarea name="counselorcomments" rows="5" cols="40" id="counselorcomments" placeholder="Comments"><?php echo set_value('counselorcomments') ?></textarea>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WM4uJ/1/)

Comment: `I am in no way fluent at using that resource` jsFiddle is just a matter of typing (or pasting) HTML & JS.  What part of that do you having trouble with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WM4uJ/ Fiddle for given information

Comment: @BeatAlex -- You forgot to select jQuery on the left.

Comment: Guys I am an idiot. I had two different actions linked up to counselorcomments. I am going to answer this question incase other noobies @ Jquery have the same issue. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was the issue :

I had #addother and #onlyother

both set to if it is checked then open #counselorcomments

so when one was checked (the #Onlyother) #addother was forcing the #counselorcomments box to to remain closed.

what I did was create another text area :

```
<textarea name="counselorcomments" rows="5" cols="40" id="emailcomments" placeholder="Emailed Counselor Comments"><?php echo set_value('counselorcomments') ?></textarea>
<textarea name="counselorcomments" rows="5" cols="40" id="counselorcomments" placeholder="Counselor Comments"><?php echo set_value('counselorcomments') ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure, what you are trying to do, but does this help?
You can use jQuery's event listener

```
.change()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WM4uJ/2/